# Buscar imágenes mediante form en un Directorio PHP

Tags: php

tengo un form donde busco datos en mi base de datos pero ahora tengo una carpeta con 800 fotos en un directorio, como lo hago para que este form pueda buscar la foto segun el input?

```html
<form id="oForm" name="oForm" method="get" action="ver_respuestas_mat.php">
       Guía :
       <input name="CODGUIA" type="text" id="CODGUIA" size="20" maxlength="20" />
       &nbsp;
       <input type="submit" name="consultar" id="consultar" value="consultar" />
</form>
```

En este form hay varias consultas hacia la BD (que no puse para que no se haga tan extenso) pero no se como con el input buscar una imagen en especifico por el nombre de la imagen y mostrarla en una tabla.

Saludos y espero que me puedan ayudar!

Comment: como haces que? esas imágenes están dadas de alta en la BD? si es así cual fue el criterio para guardarlas? subiste la imagen o solo el nombre?

Comment: además de lo anterior, que llevas hecho? con que código intentas buscar y que fallos te da?

Comment: Me explico: esas imagenes estan en un directorio X, ej: "hola/imagenes" y no puse lo demas del codigo para no hacer la pregunta muy larga

Comment: todo lo que vayas a ampliar de tu pregunta, dale editar y añádelo justo arriba

Comment: listo amigo, espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:
esto listara todas las carpetas y archivos dentro de un directorio concreto luego es solo comparar los nombres

```
function dirs($path){
    $elements=[];

    if (!is_dir($path) ) {
        echo "no is a directory";
        die;
    }

    if(!is_readable($path)) {
        $p=explode("/",$path);
        $elements[$p[count($p)-2]]="no access";
        return $elements;
    }
    $dir= scandir($path."/");
    foreach ($dir as $key => $value) {
        if ($value==".." || $value==".") {
            continue;
        }
        if (is_dir($path.$value)) {
            $pdir=trim( str_replace($path," ",$value) ) ;
            $sub=dirs($path.$value."/");
            $elements[$pdir]=$sub;

        }else{
            $elements[]=$path.$value;
        }
    }
    return $elements;
}
echo "<pre>";
$path="fotos/";
print_r(dirs($path));
```